# How to set custom folder path for sub folders in vendor when installing a package?

Tags: composer-php, package

I want to install a package into my local project.For that I'm creating a composer.json file in my project folder is given below, it gives the total vendor folder of that package into my custom folder in my project. Its working fine.....

```
{
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/var/www/html/Test2/Testing/Down"
    },
}
```

It gives the package into 'Down' folder.

But, now I want the sub folders or files in that packages to be installed in my custom folders like js/css folders in my project.

For example i want jquery.js file into my local folder path

```
  /var/www/html/Test2/Testing/assests/js
```

From the package "frameworks/jquery".

For that, what changes are needed in my composer.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified my composer.json file, it looks like the below:

```
{
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/var/www/html/Test2/Testing/Down"
    },
"require": {
},
"scripts": {
    "post-package-install": [
        "php -r \"exec('cp -r /var/www/html/Test2/Testing/Down/frameworks/jquery/* /var/www/html/Test2/Testing/assets/js');\""
    ]
}
}
```

It will gives all selected files in a package to my local folder.

Briefly the files in the folder 'frameworks/jquery' are copied into my local 'assets/js' folder.

Answer (score 1):

Composer is used to bring in packages  to support the PHP code of a project, here is how they describe it on the Composer website:

> Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to
>   declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage
>   (install/update) them for you.

In other words, if you need to do logging in your PHP code and decide to use the publicly available `monolog` package, you use composer to bring that package into your project, then in your PHP code, you can call monolog functions.

Using `config` to rename the `vendor` directory is trying to use Composer in a way that doesn't fit the intent of the tool.  The vendor directory is used to hold the packages brought in (such as the monolog code). The `vendor-dir` value is simply renaming that directory.

Since you have GitHub listed as a tag, you could possibly use cloning to get your files to your website directory.